# Simplifying convoluted if-else conditions to check if len(list) =0 - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, convolution, ternary

I am trying to check if sent1 or sent2 has zero length and if they have i want to **set** `sent_witn_not_null` as the **list with non-zero list**. But the if-else conditions, i've written seems convoluted. What is a simpler way of doing this?

```
sent1 = ["this","is","foo","bar"]
sent2 = []

if len(sent1) or len(sent2) == 0:
    sent_with_not_null = sent2 if len(sent1) == 0 else sent1
    sent_with_not_null = sent1 if len(sent2) == 0 else sent2
```

Comment: What are you even trying to do

Comment: The text says: "set sent_witn_not_null as the list with non-zero", and the code is exactly opposite.

Comment: sorry mistaken, i want the `sent_with_non_zero_len`

Comment: Also, `if len(sent1) or len(sent2) == 0` evaluates as `if (len(sent1)) or (len(sent2) == 0)`, which I assume isn't what you want.

Comment: i do what if (len(sent1)) or (len(sent2) == 0), so as to check if they either of them is zero

Comment: You need `if len(sent1) == 0 or len(sent2) == 0`, or even better, `if not sent1 or not sent2`, taking advantage of the fact that empty containers are 'falsish' values

Comment: One important question: What to do, if both lists are non-empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of Python's **coalescing operators**.

```
sent_with_not_null = sent2 and sent1
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `or` rather than `and`

Comment: No, since it takes the first empty one.

Comment: I stand corrected: "set sent_witn_not_null as the list with non-zero list" made me think that we were trying to get `sent_with_not_null` to be the non-empty one, but the code itself does seem to want it to be the empty list instead.  Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
In [4]: if sent1 or sent2:
    sent_with_not_null=sent1 if sent1 else sent2
   ...:     

In [5]: sent_with_not_null
Out[5]: ['this', 'is', 'foo', 'bar']
```

or:

```
In [11]: if any((sent1,sent2)): #in case both sent1 and sent2 are len==0

    sent_with_not_null =sent1 or sent2   #set the first True item to sent_with_not_null 
                                         #else the last one
   ....:     

In [12]: sent_with_not_null
Out[12]: ['this', 'is', 'foo', 'bar']
```